# Backbone Collection not using it's model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a simple Model:

```
App.Models.Client = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

And a simple Collection:

```
App.Collections.Clients = App.Collections.Base.extend({
    model: App.Models.Client,
    urlRoot: '/clients'
});
```

The Base collection is simple:

```
App.Collections.Base = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function() {
        return App.BaseURL + this.urlRoot;
    }
});
```

The problem is, when I do:

```
var c = new App.Collections.Clients();
c.fetch();
```

The objects in this collection are Object literals, not of type App.Model.Client

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should it be

```js
App.Collections.Base = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: function() {
        return App.BaseURL + this.urlRoot;
    }
});
```

not `Backbone.Model`